# create empty spreadsheet in google docs

Tags: php, xml, google-sheets

i want to create a empty spreadsheet with google docs api but i get the error: could not convert document.

```
$xml = "--END_OF_PART\r\n".
        "Content-Type: application/atom+xml;\r\n\r\n".      
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:docs=\"http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007\">
          <category scheme=\"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind\"
              term=\"http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#spreadsheet\"/>
            <title>".$name."</title>
        </entry>\r\n".  
        "--END_OF_PART\r\n".
        "Content-Type: text/csv;\r\n\r\n".
        "--END_OF_PART--\r\n";
```

This xml is sent to the server of google with a post with param convert=true
Then i got the error: could not convert document.
When i use the mime-type 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet' instead of 'text/csv' and do not add the param convert=true i get an internal error.

Answer (score 0):

Docs List API v3 is deprecated. Use Google Drive API instead. You can create a file with the insert call:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

the mimeType for a native spreadsheet would be:

application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet